# How to automount a USB key when plugged in on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: usb-drive, udev

This functionality worked on my 20.04 box, but is not working on my 22.04 install.

When I plug a MicroSD drive into an SD->USB device and plug that into Ubuntu it is seen as /dev/sda1, but it is not automounting.   I would like it to automount as the user I am logged in to the GUI as (or just user 1000 - I'm the only human logging in to the box)

I am manually able to mount the drive with the command

```
 sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mountpoint -o uid=1000
```

And unmount it with the corresponding umount drive manually, but this should not be necessary.

The disk has a standard VFAT filesystem on it, with label.    Following https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mount/USB I confirm that dconf-editor shows automout as on and automount-open as on.

Do I need to mess around with udev rules (which I'd prefer not to do if this is something built into the OS as I'd expect it to be)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure whats changed between version, but I needed to provide a label to the /dev/sda1 partition and everything started working as expected.

The command I used was

```
dosfslabel /dev/sda1 DISKNAME
```